# How insert array into sqlite database

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have this array

```
stokmiktarı[ ]= {04.08.2019,"Stok Miktarı",40,50,60}
```

I want to insert this array into sqlite database like this.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
Tarih      |     Isim      |   A Store   |   B Store   |   C Store  |
-------------------------------------------------------------
04.08.2019 |  Stok Miktarı |     40      |      50     |      60    |
```

How can ı do this in python please help me thanks.

Comment: are u using django/flask ...

Comment: No this cmd application

Comment: here is an example [array to sqlite3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11543264/9526947)

Comment: sorry but ı didn't understand exampla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') # creates db in RAM
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE stores_info(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, tarih DATE,
                 isim TEXT, a_store TEXT, b_store TEXT, c_store TEXT)
''')
db.commit()

stores = [
    ['04.08.2019', 'Stok Miktarı', 40,50,60],
    ['05.07.2019', 'Stok Miktarı 2', 41,51,61],
    ['06.11.2019', 'Stok Miktarı 3', 40,50,60]
]
cursor.executemany('''
    INSERT INTO stores_info(tarih, isim, a_store, b_store, c_store) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)
''', stores)
db.commit()

# retrive result
cursor.execute(''' SELECT tarih, isim, a_store, b_store, c_store FROM stores ''')
# cursor.fetchone() # retrieves the first row
result = cursor.fetchall()
for row in result:
    print row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]
```

Here is the output...

```
# by inserting a_store, b_store & tarih to db
05.07.2019 41 51
04.08.2019 40 50
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created database and tables to store this data?